# Switch To any new window

Tags: java, windows, selenium

I am writing a code using selenium.

On a particular click there are chances of coming one of two windows. and both the windows takes around 20-50 seconds of time to appear.
so i want to switch to whichever window appears.

I have no way to predict which window is going to appear 
Current process - i am searching for main window for some seconds and if it is not found i am trying to search small pop up window with ok button on it. If found click on it. if not found again try to find main window it is taking time.
If i have a way to switch to latest window and by checking its title which window it is and do the appropriate action.

Edited - main window is not the original window. There are total 3 windows in picture . One og window where i have to click . now after clicking main window can appear or small popup window can apear with ok button.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the window handle for the main window before any action is done.

```
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Now click and do the following:

You can poll for 30 seconds max time with interval say 5 seconds, break the polling the moment you get more than one window handle.

```
Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

let me know in which language you are working.

I can help you with the code.

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to mention that main window is also new window.

Comment: I am coding in java ...If you can please give me some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for your problem

```
// Store the current window handle
String mainWin = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the click operation that opens new window

//Wait till driver.getWindowHandles() returns 2 windows

// Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
//Get current window to take decision on the next actions
String currentWin= driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the actions on new window

// Close the new window
driver.close();

// Switch back to original first window
driver.switchTo().window(mainWin);
```

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to mention that main window is also new window.

Comment: Use the same logic and adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

To handle windows size, you can use `.getWindowHandles()`, and try use `while loop` to wait the new windows appear, then you can iteration again all current window.

```
int sizeBefore = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
elemnt.click();//to bring up new windows

//until current windows size>before, please keep adding timeout
while(driver.getWindowHandles().size()==sizeBefore) {
    //wait in milliseconds
    Thread.sleep(500);
}

//handle current size windows
ArrayList<String> hnds = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

//iteration windows
for(String hnd: hnds) {
    driver.switchTo().window(hnd);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

To switch to particular windows, use:

```
driver.switchTo().window(hnds.get(index));
```

Comment: Here if new window appears i have to loop through all the window handles , switch to the window and than use .getTitle() to check whether desired window is available or not. Do i have any way to directly switch to the NEW window that has appeared after the click?

Comment: `.switchTo()` to switch window, the above is suggest to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Javascript for switching wondow: below are the code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)LoginDriver).executeScript("window.open('about:blank', '-blank')");
    // To switch to the new tab
  ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(LoginDriver.getWindowHandles());
  LoginDriver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```